# How can I suppress the message `When done with this frame, type C-x 5 0`?

Tags: minibuffer, daemon, message

I am running `emacs v26` daemon on the background and using a single terminal. Usually I open files using `emacsclient -qt` and close them using `C-x C-s` and `C-x C-c` to get back to terminal run the script and afterwards re-open another file.

---

I wanted to make this operation faster where when I run `emacsclient -qt -e '(progn (find-file "file.py"))'` seems like it opens the files much faster than `emacsclient -qt file.py` (this may lag to show previous buffers for a second).

But now, when I run `emacsclient -qt -e '(progn (find-file "file.py"))'` I keep seeing `When done with this frame, type C-x 5 0` message in the minibuffer.

=> How can I suppress this warning message? and also safe to open files this way?

---

Not perfect but the script I come up with:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

open_emacs() {
    FILE=$1
    if [[ -d $FILE ]]; then
        echo "Folder path is provided, please provide a file"
        return
    fi

    if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]; then
        echo "$FILE does not exist."
        return
    fi

    if [ "$#" -ge 1 ]; then
        emacsclient -qt -e '(progn (find-file "'$FILE'"))'
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            true
        else
            emacsclient -qt -e '(progn (find-file "'$FILE'"))'
        fi
    else
        echo "## Please provide a file"
    fi
}

open_emacs file.py
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible starting from Emacs 28, which provides the user option `server-client-instructions` for this purpose.

```
(setq server-client-instructions nil)
```

Comment: I wish there was a hack to make it work for emacs26.3 too :-(

Comment: You can easily backport the change from emacs 28 to emasc 26: it's a minor change, introducing the variable that @phils describes and then using it in two places in `server-execute` to suppress the `message` calls if the variable is nil. Actually, I checked emacs 27.1, but 26 should be similar.

Comment: For anyone wanting to do that: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-diffs/2020-12/msg00151.html